# How to determine if this alternating series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k\ln k}k$ converges absolutely or conditionally?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm trying to determine if the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k\ln k }k$ is converging absolutely or conditionally.

I've tried the ratio test and removed the alternating part i.e. $(-1)^k$ and then replaced every $k$ with $k+1$ and I got this: $$\frac{\dfrac{\ln(k+1)}{k+1}}{\dfrac{\ln k }k}.$$ I now don't know how to proceed with solving this or if this is the right way to solve it.

Comment: As a remark, the Ratio Test doesn't work with logs and powers. Other tests (Cauchy condensation, comparison tests) work much better.

Comment: Okay, and if I take the alternating series test I get that $\lim{\frac{ln(k)}k}$ is equal to 0 and $\frac{ln(k)}k$ is a decreasing function. With this I proved that the series is convergent but I still don't get how does this not mean that it is absolutely convergent because I took the $(-1)^k$ and removed it.

Comment: The harmonic series is an essential series to understand convergence/divergence. How does your series compare to it?

Comment: When I go and compare this with the harmonic series, do I take $\frac{ln(k)}k < k$?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $\ln k>1$ for $k\ge 3$, so $\frac{\ln k}k>\frac1k$ for $k\ge 3$.

Comment: Ok, so $\frac{lnk}{k}$ diverges.But can we be sure that it still diverges when coupled with an alternating coefficient?

Comment: @Orm: It doesn’t: the alternating series converges by the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), since the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}x$ is decreasing for $x>e$.